# Should poor questions that have good answers be left open on JSE?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question is regarding the review queue on JSE. I've come across a poor question that has (what I think is) a good answer. I agree with the close vote- the question is not written well and seems too broad, but it has received an answer and that answer I think adds value to JSE. In this case, I have skipped the review, because my knowledge of this particular topic is poor, but I'm keen to know **what** other people think **should be done in situations where posts have poor questions, but good answers.**

The question in question is [Adding select user field in com_content to assign article to specific user](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9588/adding-select-user-field-in-com-content-to-assign-article-to-specific-user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was one of the people who voted to close this when I first saw it, and I made this decision **before** the answer was posted.

#### Why did I vote to close it?

When I saw it, it simply struck me as the sort of question by a person that showed no attempts to research the issue or try anything of his own.

These sorts of questions, in my eyes, are simply asking us to do all the work for them.

If the question does get closed, it will still be visible to the public and you always have the option to vote to re-open it.

Comment: I completely agree with you on the reason for it to be closed. It's just that at the time I wasn't sure if the answer would change anything or not. I'd forgotten that when a post is closed the question and its answers remain visible(my memory sucks). In the future, I will likely vote to close such posts.